# Apache with ProxyPass: wrong (doubled) request URI

Tags: php, mod-proxy, apache2

I've a serious and odd problem using Apache and the `ProxyPass` directive.

Here is the configuration:

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com/test/a/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/test/a/
```

When I debug the PHP `$_SERVER` I see that the `REQUEST_URI` is doubled: it should be `/test/a/` but instead is `/test/a/test/a/`.

With a wrong URI my application doesn't work.

Any clue or help is much much appreciated.

Comment: What is the initial URI? If it is `…/test/a/` then, based on your ProxyPass it is normal that the end server sees the concatenation of both `.../test/a` and the `/test/a/` in the ProxyPass

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks for helping. The initial URI is just the / of the "primary" domain, that is the domain A. The example.com is domain B, and I'd like to proxy all requests from A to B/test/a/.

Comment: The only other idea I have is to use a `RewriteRule` instead of a `ProxyPass` because you can crank up the logs in this case and really see what queries are done, to be able to discriminate between the proxy doing an invalid rewrite or the application server doing funky stuff. You can also try to sniff out the network between the two and/or enhance logs on the backend server to see what is happening.